# fetch last 5 minutes of data from oracle table

Tags: mysql, oracle

Hi i am trying to fetch last 5 minutes of data from oracle table.The query is written below and its not working somehow.

```
select * from mytable where (time_to_sec(timediff(now(),mytable.time_stamp)) <= 300)
```

Its showing this error ORA-00904.

I tried one more query.

```
select * from mytable where TIME_STAMP > (sysdate - numtodsinterval(5,'minute'))
```

Now, can you tell me the query which fetches data of last 5 minutes and which deletes data that is in the table for more than 12 hours.Thanks.

I need queries in both oracle and mysql. The mysql query i tried is here.

```
delete from mytable where (time_to_sec(timediff(now(),time_stamp))/3600 >12);
```

Comment: `time_to_sec()`, `timediff()` and `now()` are not Oracle built-in functions. Your second query looks like it should have worked - if it didn't, what happened? Or are you saying that worked, in which case why show the SQL Server query (Also what data type is your `time_stamp` column - it might be more appropriate to use `systimestamp`. Your time zone may also be a factor here though.)

Comment: thanks alot, it was an issue of time zone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In oracle subtracting 1 from timestamp means one day. And You can substract a fraction of one. So,

```
  current_timestamp - (5/(24*60))
```

gives You date from 5 minutes ago. Using that we can query:

```
select * from mytable where TIME_STAMP > current_timestamp - (5/(24*60)
```

Which should give You needed result. I find this method more straightfoward and simpler to remember than using special functions.

If You want filter out data from last 12 hours than You can query it like this:

```
select * from mytable where TIME_STAMP <= current_timestamp - 0.5
```

Comment: first i understand , but if i need data which is atleast 12 hours old, should i not write  select * from mytable where TIME_STAMP < current_timestamp - 0.5

Comment: Why did You unaccepted this answer? Is it incorrect?

Comment: actually i felt its correct and i accepted it , but i ran it and my table is not showing any data, so either there is some error else where , so i will accept as soon as it shows some data

Comment: Try `current_timestamp - INTERVAL '5' SECOND`. Best of luck

Comment: the queries above work fine for oracle, can you tell me similar queries for mysql, doing same functions